# Unable to solve error of Springboot gradle - required a bean of type 'com.myapp.services.UserDetailRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error when i use `@Autowired` for my `JPA repository interface`. I have seen this when i changed to `Gradle` from `Maven`.

I used `@ComponentScan` on my Main class but no luck. Why it is failing in Gradle.

**Error Description:**

```
Field userDetailRepository in com.myapp.controllers.UserRestController required a bean of type 'com.myapp.services.UserDetailRepository' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myapp.services.UserDetailRepository' in your configuration.
```

My Gradle (private repo renamed)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/platform" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/jcenter" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/gradle" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/maven-central" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {    
    classpath "com.target.platform:platform-connector-gradle:1.1.4"
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.18.RELEASE"

  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: "com.target.platform.connector.spring-boot"

repositories {
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/platform" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/jcenter" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/gradle" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.private.com/artifactory/maven-central" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
mainClassName = "com.myapp.Main"
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

version = "3"

distTar.version = ""

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter',
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.18.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.18.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap:1.5.18.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:1.5.18.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:1.5.18.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools",
            "org.postgresql:postgresql",
            "it.ozimov:spring-boot-email-core:0.6.3",
            "org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.27-incubating",
            "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2",
            "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2",
            "io.springfox:springfox-core:2.9.2",
            "io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.9.2")

}

configurations.all {
    exclude module:"spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
```

My Application bootstrap file

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
  }
}
```

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailRepository userDetailRepository;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public UserDetail get(@PathVariable Integer id) {
         return userDetailRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

`UserDetailRepository` JPA repository

```
public interface UserDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetail, Integer> {
    public UserDetail findOne(Integer id);
}
```

`UserDetail` Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
@XmlRootElement
public class UserDetail implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer userId;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String userName;

    .........

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like spring boot is not able to find repositories. so make the spring aware about the location of repository classes like below.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myapp.services")
```

Comment: Working... ! Thanks @Alien